# If function executing when it is not supposed to

Tags: python, if-statement

Hodwy!
I am writing a code for school in which you have to write a program that converts user input into pig Latin. My code was successful until I added a conditional statement that is required. My code is:

```
import sys
   while g < 10:  # Start an infinite loop
    
    message = input("Enter message or type stop: ")
    message = message.strip()
    
    if message == 'stop' or 'Stop':
        print('\nProgram terminated'), sys.exit()
    elif message != 'Stop' or 'stop':
        wordList = message.lower().split()
        vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
        Message_list = []
        eachWord = []
        for word in wordList:
            if word[0] in 'aeiou':  # case where vowel is first
                Message_list.append(word + 'yay')
            else:
                for letter in word:
                    if letter in 'aeiou':
                        Message_list.append(word[word.index(letter):] + word[:word.index(letter)] + 'ay')
                        break
```

I can not get proper indentation (with the while statement) on here, but in my code, the indentation is correct so that is not the problem. The code works perfectly if I remove:

```
 if message == 'stop' or 'Stop':
        print('\nProgram terminated'), sys.exit()
```

However, when I add it, the conditional always executes. I have no idea what the problem is because that is a valid conditional statement. Do any of you know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the equivalent of

```
if (message == 'stop') or 'Stop':
```

Working options include

```
if message == 'stop' or message == 'Stop':

if message in ('stop', 'Stop'):

if message.upper() == "STOP":
```